# Share tree structure between 2 instances of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following `dict`:

```py
d1 = {"parent1": {"get": {"responses": {200: {"content": {"application/json": {}}}}}}}}
d2 = {"parent2": {"get": {"responses": {200: {"content": {"application/json": {}}}}}}}}
```

I am trying to avoid code repetition so I could do this:

```py
common = {"get": {"responses": {200: {"content": {"application/json": {}}}}}}
d1 = {"parent1": common}
d2 = {"parent2": common}
```

I would basically like to know what is your *pythonic* way to get rid of the `["get"]["responses"][200]["content"]["application/json"]`:

```py
v1 = d1["parent1"]["get"]["responses"][200]["content"]["application/json"]
v2 = d2["parent2"]["get"]["responses"][200]["content"]["application/json"]
```

Comment: put it in a function?

Comment: Indeed I thought about a lambda but I was wondering if I am missing something more basic

Comment: There is no field named `spec`.

Comment: Now you are missing `get`.

Comment: Just like @depperm said, a function. You could create a function that takes a key arguement, so when calling the function you give it a key `"parent1"` .

Comment: The problem is that you are thinking of the chain of keys as a single key into a single object; it is not. If that's a query you want to make often, you should consider reorganizing/reindexing your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Less practical as the number of assignments grows:

```
v1,v2 = [d['get']["responses"][200]["content"]["application/json"] for d in (d1['parent1'],d2['parent2'])]
```

Comment: This could work nicely enough

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using library like dpath https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python

```
import dpath
    
d1 = {"parent1": {"get": {"responses": {200: {"content": {"application/json": {}}}}}}}
d2 = {"parent2": {"get": {"responses": {200: {"content": {"application/json": {}}}}}}}

path = 'parent1|get|responses|200|content|application/json|a'
dpath.new(d1, path, {'key1': 'val1'}, separator='|')
dpath.new(d2, path, {'key2': 'val2'}, separator='|')
print(dpath.get(d1, path, separator='|'))
print(dpath.get(d2, path, separator='|'))
```